# Do hearing or reciting any story in scriptures has the capability of pleasing or removing Rahu's adversary affects?

Tags: scripture, astrology, rahu

Rahu is generally considered as a malefic planet in astrology.

Many stories across scriptures has the potency to remove the negative effects by navagrahas.

Do any particular *story* mentions as phalasruthi (or believed to be) that on hearing or reciting it can remove the negative effects of *Rahu especially*.

Note that *I am asking for story only* and *asking for Rahu only*.

Comment: Did you check phalasruti of Sundarakanda? or that of Samskhepa Sundarakanda?

Comment: BTW I did check phalasrutis of Rahu Kavacham and Rahu Stotram. Both talk about reciting and not about hearing. But some other Stotras/Kavachas do mention that either reciting or hearing it being read will give you the benefits.

Comment: Oh, Please comment the names if okay for you @Rickross

Comment: For example for [Budha Kavacham](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Budha_Kavacham)'s phalasruti says --- Ya padeth **srunuyath** vapi sarvathra vijayee bhaveth.,  OR And those who read **or hear it**,
Would be victorious everywhere. .. So, it is clear that hearing the Stotra itself will get you the benefits. But the phalasruti of the Rahu Kavacham does not mention anything about what you get just by hearing the Kavacha.

Comment: I checked the pahalsruti of the Samskhepa Sundarkanda, it does not mention anything about Rahu. But hearing it being recited has lots of benefits.

Comment: @Rickross Does Budha Kavacham needs initiation?

Comment: I don't know .. no body initiated me into that but I have read it a number of times in my life so far :D You can read it. In fact individual Stotras don't usually require separate initiations. If you are initiated (either by Vedic or by Tantric ways) then you are already qualified to read many Stotras and Mantras. Like to recite the thousands of Vedic Mantras that are there you just need to be initiated into only  one Mantra (the Gayatri Mantra). What I'm saying is something similar.

Comment: @hanugm: The presiding deity of Rahu is said to be Devi.  So recitation of nAmavali of Devi or Durga Saptasathi may be beneficial

Comment: @hanugm: In the phalashruti of Durga Saptasathi, it was said - ग्रहपीडासु चोग्रासु माहात्म्यं शृणुयान्मम॥ - Those who does shravan or hearing of divine stories of Devi will be relieved of all type of problems of Grahas or planets.

Comment: Chandika is definitely mentioned as the remedy for Rahu but Devi Mahatyam does not specifically mention the same. So we can not answer with that reference. If you are looking to simply recite Stotras then directly reading Rahu Stotra/Kavacha will do (you can get them on Hindupedia) @hanugm

Comment: Yeah, I am searching for a story from Mahabharata, ramayana, or any other Purana.